PowerShell typed variable conditional assignment
I've got this code :
$u = "JohnDoe"   # This user is member of 'Domain users' and 'Test group', so memberOf returns only 'Test group'
$g = $null

if ($u)
{
    $g = [array](Get-ADUser -Identity $u -Properties memberOf|select -ExpandProperty memberOf)
}

$g.GetType()

$h = if ($u)
{
    [array](Get-ADUser -Identity $u -Properties memberOf|select -ExpandProperty memberOf)
}
else
{
    $null
}

$h.GetType()

[array]$i = if ($u)
{
    (Get-ADUser -Identity $u -Properties memberOf|select -ExpandProperty memberOf)
}
else
{
    $null
}
$i.GetType()

Can someone explain why $g.GetType() and $i.GetType(), returns this (as expected):
IsPublic IsSerial Name            BaseType
-------- -------- ----            --------                                                                                                                            
True     True     Object[]        System.Array                                                                                                                        

and why h.GetType(), returns this (absolutely not expected)
IsPublic IsSerial Name     BaseType                                                                                                                            
-------- -------- ----     --------                                                                                                                            
True     True     String   System.Object

Thanks :)

Your second if is equivalent to:
$h = if ($u)
{
    write-output [array](Get-ADUser -Identity $u -Properties memberOf|select -ExpandProperty memberOf)
  # ^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
else
{
    write-output $null

  # ^^^^^^^^^^^^
}

PowerShell is "streaming" (sometimes called "unrolling") the array of items out to the calling scope one at a time - because there's only one item being returned the result is that single System.String item being assigned to $h. If there were multiple items in the result set PowerShell would aggregate them into a new array object and assign that to $h.
It's basically the same as how return values get streamed out of functions:
function x
{
    # "bare" values get returned as-is
    1
}

write-host ((x).GetType())
# System.Int32

Your if on the other hand is doing this:
function y
{
    # single-item arrays get unrolled and the
    # first item returned instead of the array
    @( 1 )
}

write-host ((y).GetType())
System.Int32

And for completeness, comparison with returning multiple items in an array
function z
{
    # multiple-item arrays also get unrolled, but they
    # get combined into a *new* array at the receiver
    @( 1, 2 )
}

write-host ((z).GetType())
System.Object[]

You can also see the difference if you inspect the AST generated by the parser:
{
  if ($u)
  {
    $g = [array](Get-ADUser -Identity $u -Properties memberOf|select -ExpandProperty memberOf)
  }
}.Ast.EndBlock.Statements[0].Clauses[2].Item2.Statements[0].GetType().FullName
# System.Management.Automation.Language.AssignmentStatementAst

$g = [array]( ... ) is a  System.Management.Automation.Language.AssignmentStatementAst
whereas
{
  $h = if ($u) {
    [array](Get-ADUser -Identity $u -Properties memberOf|select -ExpandProperty memberOf)
  } }.Ast.EndBlock.Statements[0].Right.Clauses[0].Item2.Statements[0].GetType().FullName
# System.Management.Automation.Language.PipelineAst

[array]( ... ) is a  System.Management.Automation.Language.PipelineAst

Thanks :) I get it right away with your Write-Output explanation
